# Extending jQuery UI components ( Overriding jQuery Datepicker to prevent wrong input)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to **extend the jQuery UI Datepicker** for adding some validations.

I searched a lot in the internet, but I could not get any help. I found SO question [jquery-datepicker-function-override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725882/jquery-datepicker-function-override), there is no way to modify the textinput behaviour, the datepicker component only supports **onSelect** event, which gets fired after the date is selected not when we change the date through textinput.

I have created fiddle to show the problem.

I have two date pickers, both showing wrong dates. In this case the date picker shows the current date of the system. First textinput contains 05-ddd-2014 and second one contains 05-march-2014, both are wrong dates.

[Problem Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L59z8/1/)

---

**NOTE:**

***I know how to use the datepicker component, I want to support the validation on pressing / typing the keyboard. I need to extend the jQuery UI Datepicker component* The question is not about date format. To simplify the question, I choose simple format (dd-M-yy (i.e 02-Feb-2014)). The question is all about handling the text input change event in case of wrong dates.**

---

I am currently supporting only one input format dd-M-yy (i.e 02-Feb-2014).

When I am entering any **wrong format directly in the text input** ***(i.e 02-xxx-2014)*** , the date picker is showing the current date of the system ( current behaviour ).

Is there any way, I can validate the text entered in the text input and assign it to datepicker.

I tried using keydown event on textinput, but its not giving the correct key pressed sometimes, may be jQuery UI Datepicker is handling this event.

```
$('#datepicker').on("keydown", function(e) {
    var val = this.value;
    var ar = val.split("-");
    // dd - parse the date, do the required validation
    console.log( ar[0], isNaN(ar[0]) );
});
```

**Is there any best practice to extend jQuery UI Datepicker** or jQuery UI conmponents in general.

Comment: Would greatly appreciate if you can put your code up on JSFiddle or some other collaborative development site. It will help us figure out where exactly you are stuck. Just a thought.

Comment: You can trap the change event of the input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228689/jquery-ui-datepicker-manual-date-entry-validation

Comment: One of the best-practice I can think on the top of my head is to simply disable any free-text-entry in date-picker box.

Comment: @Sachin Sharma I need the user to be able to enter the date through textinput and datepicker ui too.

Comment: did you try $('#datepicker').on("change", function(e) { OR $('#datepicker').on("blur", function(e) {

Comment: The question asks about *Extending* jQuery UI components. I'm sure @Venky is aware of how to bind functions to events. http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/

Comment: Use sugar.js to format date as you whish and validate on blur event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `$.datepicker.parseDate( format, value, settings )` in the `blur` event, if the function returns and exception like

> A number of exceptions may be thrown:
>
> 'Invalid arguments' if either format or value is null
>
> 'Missing number at position nn' if format indicated a numeric value
>   that is not then found
>
> 'Unknown name at position nn' if format indicated day or month name
>   that is not then found
>
> 'Unexpected literal at position nn' if format indicated a literal
>   value that is not then found

If raised in the catch you can show your alert, and force a focus on the field.

Code:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
    showOtherMonths: true

}).on("blur", function (e) {
    var curDate = $(this).val();
    try {
        var r = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd-M-yy", curDate);
    } catch(e) {
        alert('Not VALID!');
        $(this).focus()
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/L6e6q/

### UPDATE

You can build your own widget eg `ui.datepicker2` usinf [`ui.widget.factory`](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/).

> Create stateful jQuery plugins using the same abstraction as all
>   jQuery UI widgets.

Using it you can extend the default and bind `keydown` and `keyup` events.

On keydown store the old value, and on keyup validate the input and if not valid, restore the old value.

Code:

```
$.widget("ui.datepicker2", {
    _init: function () {
        var $el = this.element;
        $el.datepicker(this.options);

        if (this.options && this.options.checkDate) {
            $el.on("keydown", function (e) {
                var curDate = $el.val();
                $el.attr("oldValue", curDate);
                return true;
            });
            $el.on("keyup", function (e) {
                var curDate = $el.val();
                try {
                    var r = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd-M-yy", curDate);
                } catch (ex) {
                    alert('Not VALID!');
                    $el.val($el.attr("oldValue"));
                    $el.focus();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

$(".datepicker").datepicker2({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
    showOtherMonths: true,
    checkDate: true
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/GLWT3/

Comment: Can we prevent entering the wrong date (validation on keydown). Is this the right way to extend jQuery UI components?

Comment: @Basha yes, and I build it up better; check the update

Comment: @Basha can we clear the input in keydown if the starting value is wrong?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward I am really thankful for your help. I need a bit more, Currently as per your suggestion, I am able to validate on keyup but I need more user friendly like I want to prevent the user from entering non numeric character in month and prevent the user from deleting '-' character which stands between Month, Day and  year. Is there a way to do this. I will be grateful to you.

Comment: @Venky I think we can combine a mask input plugin to achieve so (rewrite it can be long), When I have a moment I'll give a try

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward Thanks for all your help. I will try to implement it on my own and will check with your completed one. Once again thanks, you are of great help

Comment: @IrvinDominin I have a similar extension question and I am curious what your feedback might be.  Could you take a look? [How to extend jQuery UI datepicker to modify Today button and add help icon] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41066090/how-to-extend-jquery-ui-datepicker-to-modify-today-button-and-add-help-icon)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/y6XgY/177/)

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-M-dd" });

    $('#datepicker').on("keyup", function(e) {

    var val = this.value;
        if(!ValidateDate(val)){
        console.log("Date must be 2014-Mar-01 Format")
        }



});
  });


function ValidateDate(dtValue)
{
    console.log(dtValue)
var patt = new RegExp(/^20\d\d-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/);
var res = patt.test(dtValue);
return res;
}
```