# Remove highlight selected date in datepicker

Tags: jquery, user-interface, datepicker

I'm current working on datepicker, i found out that the datepicker will highlight the selected date like this by default

[image]

and i inspect this, i found that the selected date was added the class ui-state-active

[image]

so it turns out to blue. 
how can i stop the selected date by adding this class?
when i select the date, i don't want to know which day i selected.
i do tried to override the css of ui-state-active class, but when i select the 17th, it will turn the highlighted date into default. 
instead of override the css, i should stop it from adding the ui-state-active class on selected date.

how can i make it happen.

Expected result: 
when select a date, nothing highlighted

Comment: Unrelated, but if you haven't, look into `<input type = "date" />` instead of the datepicker plugin

Answer (score 0):

looking at datepicker refernce [Datepicker Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) under Theming section I noticed that the stiling css class for the selected date is "ui-datepicker-current-day" and not "ui-state-active". Maybe you can override this and get the desired behavior?
I did a small test in chrome under developer tools and I was able to modify the behavior of this control

```
td.ui-datepicker-current-day {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: the original color is blue, instead of changing it into red color, i actually wish to stop it from highlight which day was selected. Disable the onselect function may be?

Comment: Hi, I put red only to show how to override that particular css condition / property. With my code you can set transparency playing with css classes around that one. Disable onselect function means override default behavior of the datepicker and, far as I know, difficoult enough to achieve...here [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725882/jquery-datepicker-function-override) that talks about this...

Answer (score 0):

To remove active color give this css:

```
.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active, a.ui-button:active, .ui-button:active, .ui-button.ui-state-active:hover {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  color: #454545;  
}
```

Comment: i can set the selected date into default color pretending no effect on selected day. i do have the today highlighted in grey and public holiday in red. if i modified this ui-state-active to default color, when i select today, then today day will turn into default color too. this is incorrect. 
instead of override this css. i actually wish to stop it from adding the class "ui-state-active" on selected day.